# Spring + Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, java-ee, spring-mvc, jpa-2.0

Bom dia!

Estou estudando Spring MVC, Maven e Hibernate.
Na estrutura do projeto criado com Maven, onde coloco o arquivo applicationContext.xml ?

Obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

O arquivo [pode ficar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21244175/2387977) no diretório `WebContent/WEB-INF/`.

Outras boas opções são `WebContent/WEB-INF/classes/` ou `src`.